# moving zeroes to the end using stacks

Tags: java

I tried a brute force way and I thought this would work for sure but it's giving me the numbers Im not expecting. Please any advice would be highly appreciated. my logic is I put all the 0s in one stack and and all the non zeroes in one stack. And then later pop all the non zeroes to the array, and pop all the zeroes to the array. I think the logic makes sense. Here's my code

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> zeroStack = new Stack<>();
            int[] res = new int[nums.length];
            for(int i = nums.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                if(nums[i] != 0) {
                    stack.push(nums[i]);
                }
                else{
                    zeroStack.push(nums[i]);
                }
            }
            int index = 0;
            while(stack.isEmpty()) {
                res[index++] = stack.pop();
            }
            while(zeroStack.isEmpty()){
                res[index++] = stack.pop();
            }

        for(int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = res[i];
        }

        }
    }
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: please include input, expected output and actual output in your question. It makes it much easier for us to help you

Comment: @Sadap https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/567/

Answer (score 2):

```java
 while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = stack.pop();
        }
 while (!zeroStack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = zeroStack.pop();
        }
```

Above is the part you have bugs, I give the correct codes.
1. should use `!stack.isEmpty()` not `stack.isEmpty()`
2. should use zeroStack not stack again

My test code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[]{1,0,2,0,3,0};
        moveZeroes(nums);
        Arrays.stream(nums).forEach(System.out::print); // 123000
    }

    public static void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> zeroStack = new Stack<>();
        int[] res = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nums[i] != 0) {
                stack.push(nums[i]);
            } else {
                zeroStack.push(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        int index = 0;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = stack.pop();
        }
        while (!zeroStack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = zeroStack.pop();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = res[i];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Even with those fixed mistakes, the code still outputs wrong values

Answer (score 0):

Two minor mistakes in the code:

1. Since you want to iterate over the stack till the point it is **not empty**, You should use not operator in the while condition for both the stack.
2. In the second while loop, you wanted to reference `zeroStack`, but by mistake, you referenced `stack` again. So we will have to change there.

Please check the code snippet below:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class ZeroStack {
    public static void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> zeroStack = new Stack<>();
        int[] res = new int[nums.length];
        for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nums[i] != 0) {
                stack.push(nums[i]);
            } else {
                zeroStack.push(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Stack is = " + stack);
        System.out.println("zeroStack is = " + zeroStack);
        int index = 0;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = stack.pop();
        }
        while (!zeroStack.isEmpty()) {
            res[index++] = zeroStack.pop();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = res[i];
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0};
        printArray(nums);
        System.out.println("Calling moveZeroes now");
        moveZeroes(nums);
        printArray(nums);
    }
}
```

For the above code where we have `1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0` in the `nums` array, the output produced by the code is:

```
1 2 0 3 4 0 
Calling moveZeroes now
Stack is = [4, 3, 2, 1]
zeroStack is = [0, 0]
1 2 3 4 0 0
```

I have added a simple `printArray` function to check the value of array in the above code.

I hope this helps.